# ant passing all parameters to a java task

Tags: java, ant, command-line, parameters

Is there a way to pass all ant command-line parameters as properties to a java task ?

For example :
ant -Dprop1=value1 -Dprop2=value2 ... -file build.xml myTarget

```
    <target name="myTarget">
    <java classname="MyClass">
     <sysproperty ... all properties>
    </java>
    </target>
```

So the started jvm will have all properties passed from the ant command-line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<java ...>
    <syspropertyset>
        <propertyref regex=".*"/>
    </syspropertyset>
</java>
```